# Getting a File object from FileInputStream

Tags: java, android, file

I need the File object of an image on an Android device.

I'm using a function to get a FileInputStream given a URI.

```
FileInputStream getSourceStream(Uri u) throws FileNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream out = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
                getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(u, "r");
        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
        out = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor);
    } else {
        out = (FileInputStream) getContentResolver().openInputStream(u);
    }
    return out;
}
```

This returns a FileInputStream. What I need is a File object of the image. How can I get a File from FileInputStream?

**update**

This is how I am getting my URI:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), PICK_IMAGE);
```

and on `onActivityResult` I get the URI of the image.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                 Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        String uri = data.getData();
    }
}
```

Comment: FileInputStream is in memory data that is read from the URI in blocks of like 500 bytes or something, this value is configurable. What you can do is write the inputstream into a file of your own store in location you know and create a File object from that path.

Comment: @Bhargav It is read from the underlying resource precisely as indicated by the application, not in blocks of anything else. If the application reads one byte, one byte is read. There is no 'in memory data'.

Comment: @EJP well whatever bytes are read are technically in memory arent they?

Comment: @Bhargav In the application buffer passed to the `read()` methods. Not in the `FileInputStream.` Your comment states '`FileInputStream` is in memory data'. It isn't.

Comment: @EJP but buffers are supposed to be in memory aren't they? So whatever blocks of data FileInputStream reads into the buffer is in the memory right? I understand that you are trying to make the distinction between FileInputStream being in memory data and only the buffer being in memory

Comment: @Bhargav *Of course,* but that doesn't make your initial statement '`FileInputStream` is in memory data` correct. It isn't. The part about 'in blocks of like 500 bytes' is also incorrect.

Comment: @EJP Alright it was a broad generalization on my part, should've written whatever block of data is read by FileInputStream is in memory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below code to convert your FileInputStream to File object.

```
try {

        File outputFile = new File("YOUR DESIRED FILE PATH");


        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        int c;

        while ((c = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
           fos.write(c);
        }

        fileInputStream.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("FileStreamsTest: " + e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("FileStreamsTest: " + e);
    }
```

here 'fileInputStream' is your object returned by getSourceStream()